# how can I share a project-specific configuration between Aquamacs and gnu-emacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I have a .emacs.d directory shared (via git) with branches for various projects and Aquamacs seems to be ignoring it completely. All the other development systems work very well with this system so I would prefer to keep it if it can be made to work with Aquamacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquamacs uses it's own series or .emacs like files, one is called Preferences.el (this is the aquamacs equivlent of .emacs) and it's located at ~/Library/Applications Support/Aquaemacs/. Personally, I didn't like aquaemacs, and switched to Carbon emacs on OS X. All this info is in the aquamacs documentation.

Comment: will carbon emacs read the standard .emacs.d configuration directory?